# PHP のライブラリ管理

Tags: php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

というライブラリのメソッドを使用したいのですがPHPがほぼ初見でライブラリの使い方がわかりません

ライブラリ名で検索して
https://readouble.com/laravel/5.5/ja/filesystem.html
こちらのサイトを見たんですが

`php artisan storage:link`

を実行しても artisan というファイルが見つかりませんと出るだけです

MAC 上に brew install で PHP だけ入ってる状態なのですが
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
をライブラリを使用するにはどういう手順を踏めばいいのでしょうか

PHP にも Gemfile とか pip とか npm みたいなライブラリ管理ツールがあったりしますか？

Comment: 参考にしているサイトはLaravelと呼ばれるフレームワークのサイトですが、フレームワークの導入もしていないですか？[インストール 5.5 Laravel](https://readouble.com/laravel/5.5/ja/installation.html)

Comment: していないです。フレームワークとセットになってる Rails でいう ActiveRecord みたいな感じでセットでないと使えないようなものなんでしょうか？

Comment: 個別で使うのであればlaravelのサイトではなくて本家の[Flysystem](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/v2/docs/)のほうを確認したほうがいいでしょうね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。S3への読み書きがローカルファイルと同じにできるみたいで便利そうなので単独で使おうと思ってました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP では [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) でライブラリのパッケージ管理がされており、依存関係にあるライブラリも自動でインストールしてくれるようです。

Mac の場合は以下のコマンドで Composer をインストールできます。

```
$ brew install composer
```

Composer が使える状態になったら、プロジェクトごとに composer.json を用意して必要なパッケージ名やバージョンを記述、インストール…という流れになるようです。

なお、今回使おうとしているライブラリは以下になりそうです。

[illuminate/support - Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/support)

Composer に関する詳しい使い方は、例えば以下のページ等も参照してみてください。

**参考:**
[Composerの使い方 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/sano1202/items/50e5a05227d739302761)